# Increasing understanding of printing multiple variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the following Python script:

```
print("Mary had a little lamb.")
print("Its fleece was white as {}.".format('snow'))
print("And everywhere that Mary went.")

end1 = "C"
end2 = "h"
end3 = "e"
end4 = "e"
end5 = "s"
end6 = "e"
end7 = "B"
end8 = "u"
end9 = "r"
end10 = "g"
end11 = "e"
end12 = "r"

print(end1 + end2 + end3 + end4 + end5 + end6, end=' ')
print(end7 + end8 + end9 + end10 + end11 + end12)
```

I'm unsure and struggling the purpose of a very small snippet in this line:

```
print(end1 + end2 + end3 + end4 + end5 + end6, end=' ')
```

What is `end=' '` actually doing here? Are we simply declaring a variable and assigning it as a space?

When `end=' '` is present in the script the output is:

```
CheeseBurger
```

When I remove `end=' '`from the script the output is:

```
Cheese
Burger
```

Please can someone explain what this small piece of `end=' '` code is doing within my script thoroughly?

Comment: It's end of line, by default it's `‘\n’,`

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to understand, so if it is present in my script then what is it doing? Preventing a line break from occurring?